# Horse Race invalid syntax?

Tags: python, printing, syntax

I made this program, but I am getting invalid syntax at the >= sign before horse3, I am trying to print the horse with the lowest time. Thank you all again.

while True:

```
print ("Put in the time it took for all the horses to complete the race!""\n")

horse1 = float(input("Third Second's time: "))
horse2 = float(input("Glue Factory Vigilante's time: "))
horse3 = float(input("Dont forget Hoof Hearted's time: "))

if horse1 <= horse2 and <= horse3:
    print("Third Second Won!")

elif horse2 <= horse1 and <= horse3:
    print("Glue Factory Vigilanty Won!")

elif horse3 <= horse2 and <= horse1:
    print("Hoof Hearted Won!")
```

Comment: just `if horse1 <= horse2 <= horse3:`

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer here boys. Pack it up, lets go home.